# Performance of Java BigInteger on Android for crypto compute intensive applications

Tags: java, android, cryptography, biginteger, gmp

I am working on a crypto application for Android that is compute intensive.
I have to handle positive integers of size between 80 and 1024 bits.
I need modular exponentiation and a compositeness test.
I realized that the only option (if I want to code in Java only) is to use the BigInteger class.
Is there any better solution in terms of performance?
For example I thought of writing the application in C using the The GNU MP Bignum library and JNI.
Would this be worth it performance-wise?
Would that require JNI glue code just for the application entry point or there are other problems?

Comment: the best way would be to implement a small PoC of both approaches and bench it, sorry.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are wanting to code the primitives yourself? This is the sort of case where it's best to use reliable, tested libraries.

Comment: @chrylis I do research, I want to use primitives for modular arithmetic with big integers, generating primes, etc., but I have to build the rest on top of these.

Comment: OK, that's a good reason for doing these kind of things. For commercial apps, I would say: don't optimize before you are certain you actually need it.

Answer (score 4):

Android uses OpenSSL's BN API for part of its BigInteger arithmetic, so it should be fairly fast as it is. To find the slow methods, look at [Android's BigInteger documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html) for anything that has "**Implementation Note**" attached to it.

As others have noted: don't implement your own crypto primitives, because you're going to run into troubles. GMP leaks timing information for instance.